# Problems with dynamic library in Docker container

Tags: docker, qt

So, I have a project in a Docker container which uses Qt (for a C++ server application).
When I try to run the image on a different computer, I get the error message

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I made sure that the library file actually exists within the container, which it does

```
find . -name *Qt5Core*
...
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
...
```

So I assumed that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was perhaps not set properly, thus I added

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

to my Dockerfile.
The error persists, though.

Note that the other machine uses Podman instead of Docker (it does not have the actual Docker installed an I am not admin, thus I can't test if it works using Docker).
That the computer on which I created the image has Qt installed, thus it might be that the problem just doesn't surface there because it can use the library from outside the container.

Is there something I overlooked?

(I could try to copy the library file into the same folder where the executable is located within the container, but if possible, I'd prefer a cleaner solution.)

(There is this question: [Linux: Can't find existing shared library in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877174/linux-cant-find-existing-shared-library-in-docker-container) which sounded kind of similar, however, the solution there revolves around cmake, which I don't use.)

---

Edit: If relevant, when I check the dependencies of the executable within the container with `ldd` within the `CMD` instructions of the Dockerfile on the machine on which I build it, I get

```
podman run --pod my_pod -it test_server
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdb45a4000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007efcdf0ee000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007efcdeba5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007efcde9c4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007efcde9a9000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efcde7b7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efcde794000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007efcde776000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efcde770000)
libicui18n.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66 (0x00007efcde471000)
libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007efcde28b000)
libpcre2-16.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007efcde208000)
libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007efcde1f2000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007efcde0c7000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007efcddf78000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efcdf2b9000)
libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007efcdc4b7000)
libpcre.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007efcdc444000)
```

However, on the other machine, the result is

```
podman run --pod my_pod -it test_server
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff18584000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fca4e9bb000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fca4e7d2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fca4e7b7000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fca4e5c5000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fca4e5a0000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fca4e584000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fca4e57e000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fca4e42f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fca4eb86000)
```

So it only does not find the Qt Core library file. Note that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` does not exist on the other machine itself, thus it clearly is a path within the container. Another interesting find is that it *does* find `libQt5Network.so.5`, which I find rather strange given the circumstances.

---

If relevant, my Dockerfile, with some diagnostics build on for this very problem:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

    # get some basics
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
    
    # get C++ compiler
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
    
    # get Qt
RUN apt-get install -y qt5-default
RUN apt-get install -y libqt5gui5

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
    
COPY connection.cpp /
COPY connection.h /
COPY main.cpp /
COPY server.cpp /
COPY server.h /
COPY server.pro /

    # compile
RUN qmake server.pro; \
    make
    
RUN echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

EXPOSE 9999
    
CMD ldd Server; \
    /Server
```

---

Edit: I tried to add some diagnostics and another manual export for the library path in the `CMD` section of the Dockerfile:

```
CMD export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/; \
    echo '-----------------------------:'; \
    echo 'library path:'; \
    echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH; \
    echo '-----------------------------:'; \
    echo 'content relevant directory:'; \
    ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/; \
    echo '-----------------------------:'; \
    echo 'dependencies:'; \
    ldd Server; \
    /Server
```

The manual export did not help, and the `ls` again clearly shows that `libQt5Core.so.5` does in fact exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the issue. This is a very exotic bug it seems.
I found the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir and used the highest voted answer there, adding the line

```
RUN strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

to my Dockerfile.

Now my container works just fine.

If anybody has a solution that is more straight-forward, I'd be interested, though. I can't really say that I understand what's happening, what this business with the kernel one can read about under the link actually is about.