# Undefined symbol error at runtime (gcc-linux)

Tags: c++

I have compiled a library A with g++ 7.5 that references in a implementation file (.cpp) a class of another library B. But the referenced library B is not added as a dependency to library A.

app -> libA.so -> libB.so

When I run this library A with msvc & Windows, I get no error at application runtime. When run with gcc & linux, there is a undefined symbol error at application runtime.

Why is that? Why is the application running fine under windows, but not under linux? It compiles and links fine under both OS.

Comment: That's odd. Are you manually loading library `A` with `dlopen` on linux? Are you using `RTLD_LAZY` binding? Is the undefined symbol something you expect to be in `B`? Are templates involved?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly how you are linking on both OSs?  Are you using something like CMake to generate build scripts?

Comment: Yes, I actually use cmake to link the libraries on linux. The generated executable is linked to libA.so.
On windows I use Visual Studio/msbuild.

Comment: I think you need to set the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH in Linux . For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469953/why-is-cmake-designed-so-that-it-removes-runtime-path-when-installing/32470070#32470070

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I put up a zip file including the Visual Studio project files as well as the corresponding cmake files:
https://file.io/w12752O38Iaw

Comment: In the app/bin folder the binaries are included. The windows side is based on the app.sln file, the linux side is based on the build.sh file.

It took me some time and I was not able to reproduce the error with this small solution.
But: If you evaluate the libB.so (nm -u -C libB.so) and compare it to the libB.dll (depwalker), you see that the  dll doesn't contain a "typeinfo for A".

So question is: why is the symbol for class A exported on the linux build, but not on the windows build? Seems to be some cmake configuration..