# How to avoid the removal of the RPATH during CMake install step?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, rpath

I am working on a C++ project using CMake where I build an executable `foo` that uses a shared library `libbar` (that is being added via `ExternalProject_add`).

The executable `build/src/foo` in the build directory works perfectly fine. However, if I run `make install`, the installed executable `/bin/foo` gives me the following error.

```bash
./foo: error while loading shared libraries: libbar.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know I am not the only one with this problem (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469953/why-is-cmake-designed-so-that-it-removes-runtime-path-when-installing)), and I am also aware of the handling of `rpath` by CMake, see [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling). As I understand, the `install` step strips the `rpath` variable, which explains that the library file cannot be found.

I checked this by running `ldd foo` in the directory `/build/src/` resulting in

```bash
libbar.so => /PATH/TO/LIBBAR/libbar.so
```

When I run the same command in the directory `/build/bin/`, I get

```bash
libbar.so => not found
```

*Now my question.* How can I avoid in general that the executable "forgets" the location of the shared library during installation? I basically want the installed executable to have the same paths in `rpath` as the one in the `build` directory.

**What I have tried so far**

I read that you can avoid the stripping of the path via

```cpp
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

However, that does not work at all. I have no idea why not, as it is the precise solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469953/why-is-cmake-designed-so-that-it-removes-runtime-path-when-installing) and [in the documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

I can set the path manually of course via

```cpp
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$LIBBAR_PATH}/lib")
```

and that does work, but this solution is too specific to `libbar` and does e.g. not work, if I import this project in another code that also uses `libbar` via my project.

**EDIT**

I should add that this problem does not appear on all machines. I get it on Linux machines, where it also says

```
-- Set runtime path of "/PATH/TO/foo" to ""
```

during the installation. I do not get that line on my Mac, where I don't have that problem at all.

**EDIT 2**

I just saw that my problem is even mentioned explicitly on the [documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) under *Common questions*. They also say that adding `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)` is the solution. But it simply does not work for me, what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT 3**

Could it be that the `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH = True` solution does not work here, because I am adding `libbar` via `ExternalProject`? The documentation states that

> CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH is a boolean that if set to true will append directories in the linker search path and ***outside the project*** to the INSTALL_RPATH. This is used to initialize the target property INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH for all targets.

Comment: Since you know about `rpath` it shouldn't be too hard to find out that you need to set it to the library installation path for your executable `foo`. And that it's done with the `-rpath` linker option. Which is passed as `-Wl,-rpath <library installation path>` if you use the `g++` (or `c++`) front-end program.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the quick reply. The thing is, the library is already getting found by the executable in the ```build``` directory. It is just the installed executable whose rpath has been cleared. I want to find a way to simply not perform that clearing.

Comment: Perhaps you should require the third-party library to be installed first, and then use its installation directory for the rpath, by passing the option explicitly for the linker (`target_link_libraries(foo bar -Wl,-rpath,installation_path_to_bar`)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The whole point of CMake is to *not* having such compiler specific settings in your config...

Comment: @user157765 I don't quite get what makes `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` not work for you. It (together with CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE) is definitely the option to have RPATH set in the installed executable as well. Libraries don't carry RPATH. Could you elaborate a bit what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: It works when I build this project, let's call it ```A```. However, I also import the library from ```A``` into another code ```B``` (via ```FetchContent```). Now, ```B``` also uses ```libbar``` (which is why ```A``` marks it as ```PUBLIC```). But I don't want to specify the path to ```libbar``` in project ```B```  by setting the RPATH to ```external/project_A/external/libbar/libbar.so```. Especially since the executable of ```B``` that I find in the build directory already links to the right ```libbar.so``` file. (and then forgets about that during installation). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is **not** that the build `RPATH` is deleted. Those `RPATH`s are absolute paths to your build directory and will not work once they leave your machine. You don't want them there, anyway. The problem is that you aren't setting the *install* `RPATH` correctly.

Place the following code early in your project, before any targets are created.

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

if (APPLE)
  set(rbase "@loader_path")
else ()
  set(rbase "$ORIGIN")
endif ()

file(RELATIVE_PATH lib_dir
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")

# Honor user overrides, whether at the command line or FetchContent
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${rbase};${rbase}/${libdir}"
    CACHE STRING "Install RPATH")
```

This results in relocatable installation trees, and is sensitive to both GNU and Apple loader implementations that use different symbols for relative RPATHs.

This also assumes your install rules are standard and will install runtime objects to `CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR` and libraries to `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`. Adjust these as needed.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply. Unfortunately, I still get the the same error and the library file cannot be found. I played around with your solution, but did not manage to get it to work.
I also understand why in general you want the RPATH to be cleared. But in this case, I really prefer the behaviour to simply keep the RPATH during the installation, since it includes the absolute path to a library in ```/external/``` which I want to keep. I could just set it manually, but then the next project that imports my code needs to set it manually again with nested paths etc.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH is not working for you could be as simple as the ordering. This should be set before creating targets.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for all the comments and answers. I didn't find a perfect and simple answer to my question, but I want to share what I am going with for now.

As I understand it, the stripping of the `RPATH` during installation is the desired behavior, see [the documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling). In general, clearing of the `RPATH` cannot be simply deactivated. From other questions on stackoverflow, I see that there are situations where it can work to set

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

but that did not work for me. I believe that is because in my specific setup the shared library is getting downloaded and build via `ExternalProject_add`. Therefore, the shared library is not from **outside the project** in this scenario, see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH.html). (Please correct me if I am wrong on this.)

**In the end, I don't see a better way than setting the install `RPATH` manually** via

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${LIBBAR_PATH}/lib")
```

If I want to import the code that uses `libbar` (let's call it `Project_A`) into another project `Project_B`, I will have to set the `INSTALL_RPATH` in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `Project_B` as well. Something along the lines of

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${EXTERNAL_DIR}/Project_A/external/libbar/lib")
```

I don't think this is a fully satisfying soluation, but it is the best I could come up with. If anyone knows a better way, e.g. how to use the `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` option that applies to a shared library build as an `ExternalProject` in the same build tree, please feel free to show a better way.

Answer (score 1):

CMake strips the rpath’s of targets installed as such:

```
    install(
        TARGETS
            target_name
        DESTINATION
            ...
    )
```

To avoid that, install the library as file instead:

```
    install(
        FILES
            $<TARGET_FILE:target_name>
        DESTINATION
            ...
    )
```