# cmake: how to set rpath in a shared library with only target_link_directories (without target_link_libraries)?

Tags: c, cmake, dlopen, rpath

The goal of my project is as follows:
From my main executable, I want to load a library (*libfoo.so*) that loads a second library (*libbar.so*).

I want to not specify either relative or absolute paths in any `filename` arguments that I pass to `dlopen`: i.e. I'd like my code to read "`dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY)`" and not `"/path/to/libfoo.so"` or `"../to/libfoo.so"`.
My understanding is that the way shared libraries are looked up (by *libdl*) is either 1) the value of the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, 2) "embedding" *RPATH* in binaries, 3) certain standard directories known to *libdl*.

My project's directory structure is like so:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build # this directory exists to perform an "out-of-source" build with "cmake .."
├── libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── bar.c
│   └── foo.c
└── main.c
```

*main.c* can successfully do `dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY)`
I did this by adding a `target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs)` statement in the *CMakeLists.txt* that compiles *main.c*.
This seems to have the effect of adding *RPATH* in the *main* executable, as desired:

```
$ objdump -x ./main | grep PATH
  RUNPATH              /home/user/code/scratch/3/build/libs
```

But *foo.c* is unsuccessful doing `dlopen("libbar.so", RTLD_LAZY)` even though I've added a `target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` statement in its *CMakeLists.txt*.
I notice that in spite of having added the `target_link_directories` statement, *libfoo.so* does not have a *RPATH*:

```
$ objdump -x ./libs/libfoo.so | grep PATH
$
```

---

**Things I've tried**
Seemingly, *RPATH* is not added to shared libraries unless there is *at least one* `target_link_libraries` statement -- even if it's an "unnecessary" library.
I.e. if I link *libfoo.so* with *libbar.so*, then *libfoo.so* has the desired *RPATH*:

```
# Linking libbar works, but I'd prefer not to do this:
target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

...results in:

```
$ objdump -x ./libs/libfoo.so | grep PATH
  RUNPATH              /home/user/code/scratch/3/build/libs
```

...also if I link an "unnecessary" shared lib along with the `target_link_directories` statement, then also, *libfoo.so* has the desired RPATH:

```
# Linking libbar works, but I'd prefer not to do this:
# target_link_libraries(foo bar)

# Linking an unnecessary library, then doing target_link_directories also works:
target_link_libraries(foo dl)
target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

```
$ objdump -x ./libs/libfoo.so | grep PATH
  RUNPATH              /home/user/code/scratch/3/build/libs
```

---

**Questions**
Do I understand *CMake*'s behavior correctly: `target_link_directories` statements only result in a corresponding *RPATH* entry in the shared library if there is at least one `target_link_library` statement (even for an "unnecessary" lib) for the shared lib?
If that is correct, can someone please explain the rationale?

Is there another, "cleaner" way to add a *RPATH* to a shared lib (preferably with `target_link_directories`) without any "unnecessary" statements (like `target_link_library` to unnecessary libraries)?

---

**The code/files:**

```
// main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  void* handle = dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!handle) {
    printf("dlopen error: %s\n", dlerror());
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  {
    void (*fptr)() = dlsym(handle, "func");

    if (fptr) { fptr(); }
  }
  dlclose(handle);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
// libs/foo.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func() {
  void* handle = dlopen("libbar.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  printf("here in libfoo!\n");
  if (!handle) {
    printf("dlopen error: %s\n", dlerror());
    return;
  }
  {
    void (*fptr)() = dlsym(handle, "func");
    if (fptr) { fptr(); }
  }
  dlclose(handle);
}
```

```
// libs/bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

void func() {
  printf("here in libbar!\n");
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_prj)

add_subdirectory(libs)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main dl)
target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs)
```

```
# libs/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(bar SHARED bar.c)

add_library(foo SHARED foo.c)

# This is what I want, but it doesn't work:
target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# Linking libbar works, but I'd prefer not to do this:
# target_link_libraries(foo bar)

# Linking an unnecessary library, then doing target_link_directories also works:
# target_link_libraries(foo dl)
# target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: *Do I understand CMake's behavior correctly: target_link_directories statements only result in a corresponding RPATH entry in the shared library if there is at least one target_link_library statement (even for an "unnecessary" lib) for the shared lib? **Three months passed, do you find the answer now?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working build. You just need to adjust the `BUILD_RPATH` property appropriately and, if you write `install()` rules, adjust your `INSTALL_RPATH` to be similar to what I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254170/2137996). The following build is robust and adjusts the `BUILD_RPATH`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(test)

add_library(bar SHARED libs/bar.c)

add_library(foo MODULE libs/foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE bar)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
set_property(TARGET main APPEND PROPERTY BUILD_RPATH "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>")
```

The last two lines are important. You must link to `CMAKE_DL_LIBS` to portably call `dlopen` and friends. The second line makes sure the directory containing `libfoo`, which you know `main` will load, is in the `RPATH`.

Here's the console output:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build

$ cmake --build build/ --verbose
[1/6] /usr/bin/cc -Dbar_EXPORTS  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/bar.dir/libs/bar.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/bar.dir/libs/bar.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/bar.dir/libs/bar.c.o -c /home/alex/test/libs/bar.c
[2/6] /usr/bin/cc -Dfoo_EXPORTS  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/foo.dir/libs/foo.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/foo.dir/libs/foo.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/libs/foo.c.o -c /home/alex/test/libs/foo.c
[3/6] /usr/bin/cc   -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -c /home/alex/test/main.c
[4/6] : && /usr/bin/cc -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,libbar.so -o libbar.so CMakeFiles/bar.dir/libs/bar.c.o   && :
[5/6] : && /usr/bin/cc -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o -o main  -Wl,-rpath,/home/alex/test/build  -ldl && :
[6/6] : && /usr/bin/cc -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -shared  -o libfoo.so CMakeFiles/foo.dir/libs/foo.c.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/alex/test/build  libbar.so && :

$ ./build/main
here in libfoo!
here in libbar!
```

---

Answering some follow-up questions from the comments:

> [W]hat is `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>`? Is `TARGET_FILE_DIR` a CMake variable (visible in CMakeLists.txts)?

It is not a *variable*, it is a [*generator expression*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). The values of these expressions are determined after the whole configuration step has been executed. In this way, we can be sure that this expression will expand to the *actual* directory containing `libfoo.so`, not merely the one we *expect* will contain it.

In general, I prefer to use generator expressions rather than variables whenever I can. They tend to lend CMake programming a more *declarative* rather than *imperative* feel and have fewer edge cases. For example, a user might set the value of `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to something unexpected. This breaks your build if you compute the `RPATH` from `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` or something.

> [C]an you speak to the difference between `target_link_libraries(main dl)` (my version) and `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})` (your version)?

There are two differences here, both important:

1. Using `target_link_libraries` *without* a visibility specifier puts it into a weird limbo state that is *sort of* like `PRIVATE`, maybe, depending on the policy settings and whether or not any *other* calls to `target_link_libraries` have a visibility specifier. Both for clarity and to avoid these pitfalls, you should **always** specify one of `PRIVATE`, `INTERFACE`, or `PUBLIC`.
2. Using [`CMAKE_DL_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html) is **the correct way** to link to *whichever* library contains the `dlopen` family of library functions. Did you know that HP-UX uses `-ldld`? Or that AIX uses `-lld`? Or that BSDs (including macOS) don't have a separate library for that? Well, passing `-ldl` is broken for those platforms.

Using `target_link_libraries` without a visibility specifier or passing it raw link flags are both serious code smells in the modern (post CMake ~3.5) era. Try to avoid them and ask questions when you don't think you can.

Comment: @fabian - I am doing that already? Foo is the module and it depends on a shared library, bar.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I overlooked the second `add_library`

Comment: Confirmed this solution works -- thank you. Can you explain a bit more about that last line? I can sort of discern that it's "appending a property named `BUILD_RPATH`"...but what is `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:foo>`? Is `TARGET_FILE_DIR` a CMake variable (visible in CMakeLists.txts)?

Comment: One more thing I wonder if you can add to your answer: can you speak to the difference between `target_link_libraries(main dl)` (my version) and `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})` (your version)? They appear to have the same intent: to link _main_ with _libdl_, and they appear to be functionally equivalent. Is there a functional difference I'm not appreciating? Or is your version preferred style/convention in CMake?

Comment: @StoneThrow - I have updated my answer to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: @AlexReinking *we can be sure that this expression will expand to the actual directory containing `libfoo.so`, **not merely the one we expect will contain it.*** How to understand that in the right way?

Comment: @John - many factors determine the output directory within the build tree of a library or executable. The generator, the setting of several variables, etc. Using the generator expression gives you the correct result 100% of the time.