# Shared runtime libraries not found in ros2 at launch

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, ros2, colcon

I've had this issue multiple times with different libraries. The `colcon build` runs fine but at launch ros2 complaints that the shared objects were not found. Is there a better way to add the path other than setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable?

I link the external libraries (eg: libtorch) in cmake as

```
target_link_libraries(some_proj
  ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}
)

install(TARGETS some_proj
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)

ament_package()
```

Comment: Look up `RPATH` via your preferred search engine.

Comment: Ok I knew about `RPATH` found a way to do it properly, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `RPATH` as @Jesper said worked. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470070/17515609)

Apparantly the `RPATH` is stripped when the package is installed. The following setting in cmake will keep the `RPATH`

Set this in the cmake before building any targets (executables / libs)

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

Or set it for a specific target

```
set_target_properties(${some_target} PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```